# Setting current group as active group in PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7

While iterating on groups, I would like to set the current group as “an active group” in order that generated layers will be children of this active group.

Is there any pyqgis expression to do this (like for layer: iface.setActiveLayer(vl))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are generating the layers in PyQGIS as well, one way would be:

```
##Sample processing, in this case a buffer
output = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer',input,20,5,False,None)
buffer = processing.getObject(output['OUTPUT'])

root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.findGroup ('group4') #Replace with name of group you'd like layer placed in

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(buffer,True)
group.insertChildNode(-1, QgsLayerTreeLayer(buffer))
```

This way, your output layer (of **QgsVectorLayer** type) will be added to the bottom of the group named 'group4'. This will also work regardless of which groups are currently active.

[image]